# Can't install theme

Tags: angular, angular-material

Can't install Angular Material pre-built theme. Installed all components, linked a .css file. Still have save error:

> Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Added to .css:
`@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"`

Installed all components @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations and imported all modules: BrowserAnimationsModule, MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule.

Expecting to see slick material design.

Comment: Where did you import the theme file?

Comment: @Lbovsky can share minimal code on `stackblitz`?

Comment: @IvanS95 to the app.component.css.

Comment: You should import it in `styles.css` not on the component's css, alternatively you can link it in `index.html` with `<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">` in the head tag

Comment: @Abhishek https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9b94lr

Comment: @IvanS95 thanks a lot. I knew a solution is simple, now it works:)

Comment: No prob :) added it as an answer for others to see

Comment: @Lbovsky you can add this `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"` in app.component.css change this to style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme file should be imported in the global `styles.css` file of your application, according to Angular Material [Docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming):

> If you're using Angular CLI, this is as simple as including one line
>   in your **styles.css** file:
>
> `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`
>
> Alternatively, you can just reference the file directly. This would
>   look something like:
>
> `<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
>   rel="stylesheet">`